# MinGW compiles the program and creates the .exe, but Eclipse doesn't run it

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I have installed MinGW and then ran Eclipse, but something must have gone wrong somewhere.

I have done this process on other machines and from Eclipse I've been able to compile and run the program.
However, on my own machine (figures...!) MinGW does create the .exe when I select "build" from within Eclipse, but then it won't run.

To run programs I've had to go into my project folder, copy all relevant .dlls in there, and running manually...
Needless to say this is a pain and as I'm only learning C++ still, I have a lot of projects and those .dlls copied everywhere are starting to take up a lot of space.

Have I missed anything?
Is there a way to fix this?

I have already tried uninstalling everything and re-downloading both MinGW and Eclipse, but no luck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check this question out, it might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492329/eclipse-c-dll-import

Comment: what dlls exactly? you need to copy the dlls from mingw/bin folder to your project? or some other ones?

Comment: the required dlls to run my programs have only been two so far: 1) libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll , and 2) libstdc++-6.dll.

Comment: also, thanks for the link, but it seems to be a different problem. as i mentioned, on my work machine i can just run eclipse, write any simple code, compile and run it, without importing any dlls or doing any extra stuff - just having installed mingw beforehand... so i don't think importing dlls would be a required step?

Comment: Normally, these two files are located in the directory `c:\MinGW\bin` . Have you in the PATH environment variable a entry pointing to that.

Comment: thanks - that's where i took them from :) i have double checked and yeah, there is a link to that folder in the PATH.

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't run"? What happens when you try? (There are infinitely many things that don't happen; tell us what does happen.)

Comment: a small message window opens and closes too fast for me to see anything in it, and that's it - i get no errors or messages on the internal console, problems, etc. it's not my program closing fast (crashing or otherwise - works fine when i manually launch the exe). i have tried adding "-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc" to the mingw c++ linker in the project settings, but this launches the program in eclipse's own console rather than independently...
(thanks for the help, by the way! :) )